# Cannot connect to Tomcat web socket behind Apache

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, spring-websocket, stomp

When I tried to connect to Spring Boot web socket from Android stomp client, it is not connecting and the Catalina log shows

```
Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
```

Tomcat server is running behind Apache and the Apache server runs on https. **I haven't added https in Tomcat** .All the http requests are redirected to https this is how I tried to connect to the websocket

```
mStompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.JWS, "wss://chat.example.com/ws/chat/websocket", headers);
```

but it works when running in local machine

```
mStompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.JWS, "http://10.0.2.2:8080/chat/ws/chat/websocket", headers);
```

this is my stomp end point setup

```
registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setHandshakeHandler(new HandShakeHandler()).withSockJS();
```

I have enabled `mod proxy wstunnel` and in the virtual host config I have added

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/chat/
proxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/chat/
ProxyPass /wss/ ws://localhost:8080/chat/
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please check if your production server as ELB installed. Because web socket does not work on ELB for that you need to install ALB.

Comment: @NileshKumar, thanks for the quick reply. Sorry I am not a server expert can you please tell what is ELB and ALB?

Comment: Please read documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/what-is-load-balancing.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html

Comment: Sorry, the server is running on digital ocean

Comment: Could you please cross check if ELB is installed on your digital ocean server.https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/load-balancers/

Comment: I am not using a load balancer, just a single tomcat instance running behind apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [this server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/837104/apache-2-4-7-mod-proxy-wstunnel-tunneling-too-much-http-as-well-as-ws) lin. I have to add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule /api/(.*) ws://newapp.example.com:8080/api/$1 [P]
```

and changed the last line to

```
RewriteRule /chat/(.*) ws://localhost:8080/chat/chat/$1 [P]
```

and now it is connected

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be in the order of your proxy commands:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/chat/
proxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/chat/
ProxyPass /wss/ ws://localhost:8080/chat/
```

See the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> #### Ordering ProxyPass Directives
>
> The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins. So usually you should sort conflicting ProxyPass rules starting with the longest URLs first.

Since the first rule matches the `/wss/` URLs, the later rule is *never* triggered. The correct order is:

```
ProxyPass /wss/ ws://localhost:8080/chat/
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/chat/
proxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/chat/
```

(I'm not sure if you need a reverse rule or not.)

I've spent hours trying to make the redirect rules work on my system but apparently you don't need them at all.